# MySQL Query with multiple AND statements seems to be ignoring one

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a query on a MySQL database, but I found that it seems to be ignoring the 'status' item.

```
SELECT * FROM  `posts`  
WHERE
      `tags` LIKE '%gda%' 
   OR `tags` LIKE '%contests%' 
   OR `tags` LIKE '%merch%' 
  AND `newsID` != '2134' 
  AND `status` > '1' 
ORDER BY  `postDate` DESC  LIMIT 5
```

In that example, it's still pulling items even if 'status' is set to 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is with the priority of `OR`/`AND` conditions. `AND` has a higher priority than `OR`, that's why it firstly evaluates all conditions connected by `AND` (tags-merch, newsID-2134 and status-1) and then evaluates the both tags-gda and tags-contests).

Try to add the brackets:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM  `posts`  
 WHERE (`tags` LIKE  '%gda%' 
    OR  `tags` LIKE  '%contests%' 
    OR  `tags` LIKE  '%merch%')
   AND  `newsID` !=  '2134' 
   AND `status` > '1' 
ORDER BY  `postDate` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Worked. This is the first time I start using queries complicated enough where stuff like this becomes an issue. Makes sense though, thanks for the explanation and sample.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM  `posts`  
WHERE
     ( `tags` LIKE '%gda%' 
   OR `tags` LIKE '%contests%' 
   OR `tags` LIKE '%merch%')
  AND `newsID` != '2134' 
  AND `status` > '1' 
ORDER BY  `postDate` DESC  LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use some brackets I don't know what combinations you want but try this:

```
  SELECT * FROM  `posts`  
    WHERE
         ( `tags` LIKE '%gda%' 
       OR `tags` LIKE '%contests%' 
       OR `tags` LIKE '%merch%' 
      )
      AND `newsID` != '2134' 
      AND `status` > '1' 
    ORDER BY  `postDate` DESC  LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually mixing ORs and ANDs is not a smart practice, since you'll get different results based on the execution order and the operator precedence, e.g, `true or true and false`, can be evaluated as `(true or true) and false` - yielding false or as `true or (true and false)` - yielding true.

Use parentheses to separate the ORs and the ANDs, and the execution order will be explicit, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  `posts`
WHERE (`tags` LIKE '%gda%' OR `tags` LIKE '%contests%' OR `tags` LIKE '%merch%')
  AND `newsID` != '2134'
  AND `status` > '1'
ORDER BY  `postDate` DESC  LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to **use brackets to emphasize your logical sentences**. Such as:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM  `posts`  
 WHERE  (`tags` LIKE  '%gda%' OR  `tags` LIKE  '%contests%' OR  `tags` LIKE  '%merch%') 
   AND  `newsID` !=  '2134' 
   AND `status` > '1' 
ORDER BY  `postDate` DESC  LIMIT 5
```

Otherwise, your logic gets lost. Also **using brackets makes easier to read your SQL sentences**.