# IF VAR is in mySQL database then return that rows data as variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I've tried like twenty times and the closest I got was when I put in a variable stored in row 1 of the db and it returned the content the last row in the db. Any clarity would be extremely helpful. Thanks.

```
// Create connection
$coco = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);
// Check connection
if (!$coco) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }
// Start SQL Query
$grabit = "SELECT title, number FROM the_one WHERE title = 'on' AND (number = 'two' OR number='0')";
$result = mysqli_query($coco, $grabit);
// What I need it to do
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $titleit = $row["title"];
        $placeit = $row["number"];      
        $incoming = 'Help';
        if ($titleit[$_REQUEST[$incoming]]){
            $message = strip_tags(substr($placeit,0,140)); 
        }
        echo $message;
    }
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
mysqli_close($coco);
```

Comment: What is `if ($titleit[$_REQUEST[$incoming]])` trying to do? `$titleit` is a string, why are you accessing it as an array?

Comment: so because $titleit is not an array, how can check to see if $incoming is in $row["title"];

Comment: `if ($titleit == $_REQUEST[$incoming])`

Comment: But `$titleit` will always be `on`, because that's all you select in the SQL.

Comment: The variable `$titlit` contains the value that you read out of the database, with `$titleit = $row["title"]`.

Comment: I want to first see if the string assigned to $incoming is in the database title field and if it is I want to assign some of the row data to $message.

Comment: Do you mean you want to compare? `if ($titleit == $_REQUEST[$incoming])` then it is better to put it in the Select-query as in the answer from @Barmar

Comment: yes compare.  If $incoming is say 'Apple' and compares/matches the value of Apple on row 3 of the $row["title"] in the db, I want to be able to assign the value stored in $row["number"] to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add a break; in that if or I would assume it would go through each row in the database and set message if it matches the conditional.  Unless you want the last entry that matches...if not you should debug:

```
if ($titleit[$_REQUEST[$incoming]]){
    // set message
}
```

and see when it's getting set.  That may not be the issue, but it's at least a performance thing and could explain getting the last entry

Have you tried print_r($row) to see the row or adding echos to the if/else to see what path it's taking?

Comment: print_r is to display the array and echo the values? kind of right?

Comment: print_r is similar to var_dump...it will output the row in the database in a form that we can read.  For more on it, check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php.  I use this a lot with objects, resources, and things that can't be output as strings with echo.  Echo I would use for something like $row['title'] to see the field value.  Check http://php.net/ECHO for more on that.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I like Bamars answer though...you can use WHERE in your SQL statement and then wouldn't have to worry about all this.  Just trying to help :)

Comment: How do I add more conditions to the WHERE?  Can I use AND again?

Comment: You should be able to use AND again.  Just do some Google-fu on MySQL with multiple ANDs for the WHERE clauses.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733312/mysql-query-with-multiple-and-statements-seems-to-be-ignoring-one  has some conversation about brackets and such.

Comment: Solid!  A week of my life later I have been informed!

Answer (score 2):

Put the input that you want to match into the `WHERE` clause of the query, rather than selecting everything and then testing it in PHP.

```
$incoming = mysqli_real_escape_string($coco, $_POST['Help']));
$grabit = "SELECT number FROM the_one WHERE title = '$incoming' AND number IN ('two', '0')";
$result = mysqli_query($coco, $grabit);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['number'];
    }
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Comment: Solid! is there a way to add another check in the WHERE?